# explicit conversion integer float System.out in Java

Tags: java

Hey guys I'm a new Java learner. I have a problem with this code:
I dont see why it prints only the value of a, and not of ((9/5)*a+32)
for example if a = 50 , ((9/5)*a+32) = 82 but when I compile this it prints a=50 and  ((9/5)*a+32)=82.

```
    Scanner tt = new Scanner(System.in);
            a = tt.nextInt();
            System.out.println(a + " degrees °C match  " + ((9/5)*a+32) + "°F");
```

Can someone explain this to me?!

Comment: What is the type of `a`?

Comment: did you mean that it prints 82?

Comment: the reasong being 9/5 is an integer division

Comment: is there any relation between your title and description of question ?

Comment: yes it should print 82. a is an integer.

Comment: I would love if the compiler would flag `9/5` at least as a warning, was there is hardly a reason where you want this to become 1.

Comment: if `a=82` it will print `114` not `82`

Comment: If a is int, Your code is working as it is..

Comment: so what should I do to make it print 122 instead of 82

Comment: Ahh I got it Mister Smith. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

9/5 is being done using integer maths. In integer, 9/5 is 1.

Try:

```
(9*a)/5+32
```

or:

```
(int)((9.0/5)*a+32)
```

Comment: That should be a comment

Comment: @dystroy No it shouldn't. It's an answer to the question.

Comment: It is now that the question completely changed ^^

Answer (score 0):

try using

```
 1.80 * a + 32
```

or

```
 9 / 5.0 * a + 32
```

what happens in your code is that you are dividing an `integer` by `integer` and

> integer / integer = integer

it leads to precision loss..so you have to convert it to `float` or `double` type.

Answer (score 0):

You are performing integer division, I believe you wanted

```
System.out.println(a + " degrees °C match  "
    + ((((double) 9) / 5) * a + 32) + "°F");
```